# Drawing UITableViewCell in IB

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, interface-builder

Is it bad practice/not efficient to draw UITableViewCell in IB vs drawing in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at all - Apple recommend it and provide an example of how to do it. See [Table View Programming Guide - scroll down to Loading Custom Table-View Cells From Nib Files](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1) - just make sure you follow the other recommendations regarding use of transparency, cell reuse, etc.